# How can I place the output of different button functions in tkinter in a particular frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python.

On clicking the button "check connection", I want the message to be displayed in the tkinter window itself, rather than a message box... I want the output of every button function in the same place in the tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess


root = Tk()
root.geometry("850x500+300+300")

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Windows")
        #self.style = Style()
        #self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Windows")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Check Wired Connections",command = self.checkconnections)
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Check Wireless Connections")
        cbtn.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=4)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK")
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.v = StringVar()
        messagelabel=Label(self, textvariable=self.v)
        messagelabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=0)



    def checkconnections(self):
        p = subprocess.call('nm-tool')
        print p
        self.v.set(p)

def main():

    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: y have changed the subprocess from check_output to call . i think check_output is good

Comment: thanku i got the output..thanks for answering so many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then create label in your class

```
class Example(Frame):
   .....
   self.v = StringVar()
   messagelabel=Label(self, textvariable=v).pack()
   self.v.set("")
   ......
   def checkconnections():
    p1 = subprocess.check_output('nm-tool' )
    self.v.set('nm-tool', p1)
```

---

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess


root = Tk()
root.geometry("850x500+300+300")

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Windows")
        #self.style = Style()
        #self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Windows")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Check Wired Connections",command = self.checkconnections)
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Check Wireless Connections")
        cbtn.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=4)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK")
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.v = StringVar()
        messagelabel=Label(self, textvariable=self.v)
        messagelabel.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=0)



    def checkconnections(self):
        self.v.set("hai")

def main():

    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: hey could you please tell me exactly where i shoul place these lines in my code...cause i'm getting an error

Comment: i did not understand whether i should place the function checkconnectons inside the class or outside the class

Comment: @user9213 in your example class place the first three in the example class and your function inside the class

Comment: @user9213 remeber in class you need to call method using self.checkconnections .place this where you use commands eg:Button(self, text="Check Wired Connections",command = self.checkconnections)

Comment: i am getting error like set should have attributes..could you please edit my code post the answer

Comment: @user9213 Ok please give me sometime

Comment: @user9213 please check now in connection function give the subprocess output and please place it some where where you want

Comment: thanks...but i replaced the function with subprocess call...i still get the output in the console..sorry for bothering you so many times

Comment: @user9213 its ok can you place your code in your question what have you tried so far as it is ? so that i can find the issue

Comment: @user9213 the problem is i think your working inlinux but i am in windows.though when i print p  i get 1 as output.please try to print p and check what result r coming

Comment: NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        BC:EE:7B:73:FC:D3

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.112
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.2

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             4.2.2.2

Comment: yea i am using linx i get the above output when i print p